# getApplicationContext() not working for JobScheduler which uses AsyncTask for JobService

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I am using `JobScheduler` which uses `AsyncTask` for its `JobService`. In the class `MJobExecutor` which extends `AsyncTask` uses `MediaPlayer` which needs `getApplicationContext()` as argument is not working. It shows cannot resolve method.

```
public class MJobExecutor extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
ValueExchange value;
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    value = new ValueExchange();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date=cal.getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String formattedDate=dateFormat.format(date);
    if(formattedDate.equals(value.getString())){

    }
    return "Long running task finishes." + value.getString();
}

private void play(){
    if(player == null){

        player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.bensoundfunkyelement);
        //In the above code getApplicationContext() not working-
        //Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext()
        //i have used this as context not working.
        //getBaseActivity() not working.
        //getActivity().getApplicationContext() also not working.


      player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
    player.start();
}
private void stop(){
    stopPlayer();
}
private void stopPlayer(){
    if(player != null){
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}


}
```

Below is the `MainActivity` file. There is no problem in this file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int JOB_ID = 101;
JobScheduler jobScheduler;
JobInfo jobInfo;



TextView textTime;
ImageButton ibLeft,ibRight,ibTop,ibBottom;
TextClock textClock;



String alarmTime = "12:00 AM";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    textTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ibLeft = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.left);
    ibRight = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.right);
    ibTop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.top);
    ibBottom = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bottom);

    textClock.setPadding(0,250,0,0);


    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,MJobScheduler.class);
    PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
    bundle.putString("alarmTime",alarmTime);

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,componentName);

    builder.setExtras(bundle);
    builder.setPeriodic(5000);
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
    builder.setPersisted(true);
    jobInfo = builder.build();
    jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);



}


public void Start(View view) {

    jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Job Started...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void Stop(View view) {
    jobScheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Job Cancelled...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

Below is `MjobExecutor` class which extends `JobService` calls `MJobExecutor` class which extends `AsyncTask`. It seems there is also no problem in this class.

```
public class MJobScheduler extends JobService {
MJobExecutor mJobExecutor;
String alarmTime;
ValueExchange value;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
    alarmTime = params.getExtras().getString("alarmTime");
    value = new ValueExchange();
    value.setString(alarmTime);
    mJobExecutor = new MJobExecutor(){

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),alarmTime+" "+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            jobFinished(params,false);
        }
    };
    mJobExecutor.execute();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    mJobExecutor.cancel(false);
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You can also make MJobExecutor as an inner class which can access all content of MJobScheduler.

Comment: hi thanks. long back i was doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AsyncTask class MJobExecutor should have constructor which passes context or media player object

```
    public class MJobExecuter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private Context context;

public YourTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    // todo
    return null;
}

    }
```

And then in the class MJobScheduler which extends service which calls AsyncTask should pass the Context as shown.

```
    public class MJobScheduler extends JobService {
    MJobExecutor mJobExecutor;
    String alarmTime;
    ValueExchange value;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        alarmTime = params.getExtras().getString("alarmTime");
value = new ValueExchange();
value.setString(alarmTime);
mJobExecutor = new MJobExecutor(getApplicationonContext()){//pass context here..

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),alarmTime+" "+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        jobFinished(params,false);
    }
};
mJobExecutor.execute();
return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
mJobExecutor.cancel(false);
return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `getApplicationContext()` from inside an `AsyncTask` because that method is defined in the `Context` class and not in the class `AsyncTask`. FYI, you can use this method from `Activity` or `Service` or their subclasses because those classes are subclasses of `Context`.

In order to solve your problem, you will need to pass a `Context` object or a `MediaPlayer` object in your `AsyncTask` via constructor or setter.

For example:

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private MediaPlayer player;

    public YourTask(MediaPlayer player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // todo
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just add the following constructor in your class `MJobExecutor` - public MJobExecutor(MediaPlayer player) { this.player = player; }

Comment: i have added private MediaPlayer player;
    public MJobExecutor(MediaPlayer player){
        this.player = player;
    } in MJobExecutor an then mJobExecutor = new MJobExecutor(player){  } but  still not working...

Comment: The method `getApplicationContext()` won't work inside your `AsyncTask`, but it you can remove that line as `player` is already initialized.

Comment: the code doesn't works.Please look at this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147674/how-to-pass-mediaplayer-object-to-asynctask-from-jobservice-of-jobscheduler